# Angular UI router not resolving injected parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

So consider the following fragment from my angularUI routing setup. I am navigating to the route  /category/manage/4/details (for example). I expect 'category' to be resolved before the relevant controller loads, and indeed it is to the extent that I can put a breakpoint inside the resolve function that returns the category from the category service and see that the category has been returned. Now putting another breakpoint inside the controller itself I can see that 'category' is always undefined. It is not injected by UI router.

Can anyone see the problem? It may be somewhere other than in the code I've provided but as I have no errors when I run the code, it's impossible to tell where the source of the issue might lie. Typical js silent failures!

```
        .state('category.manage', {
            url: '/manage',
            templateUrl: '/main/category/tree',
            controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
        })
        .state('category.manage.view', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/{categoryId:[0-9]*}',
            resolve: {
                category: ['CategoryService', '$stateParams', function (CategoryService, $stateParams) {
                    return CategoryService.getCategory($stateParams.categoryId).then(returnData); //this line runs before the controller is instantiated
                }]
            },
            views: {
                'category-content': {
                    templateUrl: '/main/category/ribbon',
                    controller: ['$scope', 'category', function ($scope, category) {
                        $scope.category = category; //category is always undefined, i.e., UI router is not injecting it
                    }]
                }
            },
        })
            .state('category.manage.view.details', {
                url: '/details',
                data: { mode: 'view' },
                templateUrl: '/main/category/details',
                controller: 'CategoryDetailsCtrl as details'
            })
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The concept is working. I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KmBt7REPrcZgwqUjUhIK?p=preview). The changes is here

instead of this

```
resolve: {
    category: ['CategoryService', '$stateParams', function (CategoryService, $stateParams) {
        //this line runs before the controller is instantiated
        return CategoryService.getCategory($stateParams.categoryId).then(returnData); 
    }]
},
```

I just returned the result of the getCategory...

```
resolve: {
    category: ['CategoryService', '$stateParams', function (CategoryService, $stateParams) {
      return CategoryService.getCategory($stateParams.categoryId); // not then
    }]
},
```

with naive service implementation:

```
.factory('CategoryService', function() {return {
  getCategory : function(id){
    return { category : 'SuperClass', categoryId: id };
  }
}});
```

even if that would be a promise... resolve will wait until it is processed...

```
.factory('CategoryService', function($timeout) {return {
  getCategory : function(id){
    return $timeout(function() {
        return { category : 'SuperClass', categoryId: id };
    }, 500);
  }
}});
```

Comment: Thank you! Absolutely right. The strange part is I've been using that syntax with the $http service and that always worked fine, and given that my category service returns a promise I assumed it would work the same. I'll need to work out what the difference is, but thanks again for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't see any documentation of this usage. and in the document it shows that the resolve object has key, factory. and the factory only accept string or function...

Comment: Finally was able to resolve my own issue with this solution. Thanks!