# AngularJS injection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble finding what's wrong in my code.

so, i'm resolving an http.get with ui-route and then calling the controller.

Elsewhere it works fine, but in a particular controller it don't

So, in my route.js i have this

```js
.state('post', {
         url: '/post/{id}',
         templateUrl: 'post.php',
         resolve: {
           post: ['$http','$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
             return $http.get('link' + $stateParams.id)
                .then(function(data) {
                   return  data.data; });
     }]
 },
      controller: 'PostController',
       })
```

and the, in my controller i have this:

```js
App.controller('PostController',['$scope', 'post', function PostController($scope, post) {
$scope.posts = post;
  }]);
```

i get as i said an injection problem on post [$injector:unpr] (Unknown provider: postProvider <- post <- PostController), but i can see the http.get data in my controller. What am i missing?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623574/angular-ui-router-not-resolving-injected-parameters) out for possible duplicate.

Comment: @C0dekid Probably because it's just a partial snippet, so `.state('post', {` is meaningless in the current snippet context

Comment: @lintmouse: no it doesn't seem the same, if i put a console log in my controller 
console.log(post);
i can see the data that i want to use, but still it says that the variable isn't injected or something and it's not binded in my page