# Error: $injector:strictdi Explicit annotation required but it is implemented - linked to angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm getting a, to me, nonsensical error message because I am doing what it says I'm not doing.

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(labelsResource)
```

And the code it's complaining about is the one below, exactly (but I removed the actual logic in the function labelsResource):

```
(function (module, angular) {
    "use strict";

    var labelsResource = function ($resource, $timeout, salesFlowsContext, applicationConfiguration) { ... };

    labelsResource.$inject = ["$resource", "$timeout", "salesFlowsContext", "applicationConfiguration"];

    module.factory("labelsResource", labelsResource);
}(
    angular.module("common.translation"),
    angular
));
```

I even tried to make it work by removing "use strict" but the error remains. What am I overlooking?

Similar questions have no answers or work for me.

**Edit**: In the mean time I learned that it seems to be linked to my upgrade of angular-ui-router.
I'm currently using version 0.2.14 but when I move to version 1.0.10 I get the error.
If I don't move to a newer version of the router, everything loads but instead I get numerous errors linked to angular-ui-router:

```
Error: transition superseded
Error: transition prevented
Error: transition failed
```

Which version of Angular-ui-router should I use so that I can successfully make angular 1.6.5 work?

**Edit 2:**

It's probably related to the new ui-router. the issues arises here:

```
        $stateProvider
        .state({
            name: "root",
            "abstract": true,
            template: "<ui-view/>",
            resolve: {
                labelsResource: "labelsResource",
                codingSchemesResource: "codingSchemesResource",
                translation: function (labelsResource) {
                    return labelsResource.getLabels();
                },
                codingSchemesTranslation: function (codingSchemesResource) {
                    return codingSchemesResource.getCodingSchemes();
                }
            },
            controller: "RootController",
            controllerAs: "root"
        })
```

when it gets to the labelsResource and ui-router tries to do the following:

```
// This effectively calls $get() on `$uiRouterProvider` to trigger init (when ng enters runtime)
runBlock.$inject = ['$injector', '$q', '$uiRouter'];
function runBlock($injector, $q, $uiRouter) {
services.$injector = $injector;
services.$q = $q;
// The $injector is now available.
// Find any resolvables that had dependency annotation deferred
$uiRouter.stateRegistry.get()
    .map(function (x) { return x.$$state().resolvables; })
    .reduce(unnestR, [])
    .filter(function (x) { return x.deps === "deferred"; })
    .forEach(function (resolvable) { return resolvable.deps = $injector.annotate(resolvable.resolveFn, $injector.strictDi); });
}
```

It fails the $injector.annote code:

```
function annotate(fn, strictDi, name) {
    var $inject, argDecl, last;

    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
        if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
            $inject = [];
            if (fn.length) {
                if (strictDi) {
                    if (!isString(name) || !name) {
                        name = fn.name || anonFn(fn);
                    }
                    throw $injectorMinErr('strictdi', '{0} is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode', name);
                }
                argDecl = extractArgs(fn);
                forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg) {
                    arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name) {
                        $inject.push(name);
                    });
                });
            }
            fn.$inject = $inject;
        }
    } else if (isArray(fn)) {
        last = fn.length - 1;
        assertArgFn(fn[last], 'fn');
        $inject = fn.slice(0, last);
    } else {
        assertArgFn(fn, 'fn', true);
    }
    return $inject;
}
```

I have no idea why. This worked in angularjs 1.5.8 and ui-router 0.2.14.

Comment: does other dependencies like `salesFlowsContext` & `applicationConfiguration` has followed strictdi?

Comment: yes, also like to add that I'm moving from version 1.5.8 to 1.6.5 and I didn't have this issue in 1.5.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for my issue through a similar question asked:
[angular-ui-router not resolving injected parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623574/angular-ui-router-not-resolving-injected-parameters)

It wasn't the same issue but after seeing the answer of the above question, the simple solution finally hit me. Can't believe it took half a day for it to get through to me...

I just had to inject like I do for any other function such as those when making a new module.

So the solution for the following piece of code:

```
resolve: {
    labelsResource: "labelsResource",
    codingSchemesResource: "codingSchemesResource",
    translation: function (labelsResource) {
        return labelsResource.getLabels();
    },
    codingSchemesTranslation: function (codingSchemesResource) {
        return codingSchemesResource.getCodingSchemes();
    }
}
```

Is the following

```
 resolve: {
     labelsResource: "labelsResource",
     codingSchemesResource: "codingSchemesResource",
     translation: ["labelsResource", function (labelsResource) {
         return labelsResource.getLabels();
     }],
     codingSchemesTranslation: ["codingSchemesResource", function (codingSchemesResource) {
         return codingSchemesResource.getCodingSchemes();
     }]
 }
```

Comment: The `labelsResource: "labelsResource"` and `codingSchemesResource: "codingSchemesResources"` seem unnecessary in any case.  Why do you have them?

Comment: I thought they were necessary to use them in the translations below them. So I guess I don't need them?